# How to have an uiimageview like a background image of an uiview with an uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, background, uiimageview, dimensions

i have an uiview with a uiscrollview and an uiimageview like background of uiview. In viewDidLoad to have scroll i use this:

```
CGSize scrollViewSize = [self.view sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
scrollViewSize.height = 700.0;
scroll.contentSize = scrollViewSize;
```

The problem is that background image will not fill the entire scrollview but only the dimension of screen. What can i do? i load this uiview in this way:

```
MyViewController *contr = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:contr animated:YES];
```

In InterfaceBuilder uiimageview have mode scaletoFill. 
Help me pls!

Answer (score 0):

Just get a reference to you imageView with an IBOutlet and then adjust its size as you adjust the scroll content size.

Comment: done.. but nothing! in .h UIImageView *back; @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *back; In viewDidLoad : after setting uiscrollview i made: [self.back setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,scroll.size.width,scroll.size.height)]; but nothing :(

Comment: Did you think to link the Image into IB ? Write @syntesize ?

Comment: You must not use size but content size.

Comment: i wrote @syntesize! what can i do with content size?

Comment: @JackTurky:[self.back setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,scroll.contentsize.width,scroll.contentsize.height)]; after changing it of course.

Comment: @JackTurky : this is another problem :-) You still set its size to scrollViewSize do you ?